# Js lib works in vanilla js but throws error at instantiation in basic create-react-app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

In short:

A certain node library works in vanilla js but throws error at instantiation in a basic create-react-app. Why?

---

I'm trying to use this [kinect-azure](https://github.com/wouterverweirder/kinect-azure) library in a basic create-react-app app. The library works in the following vanilla js script (using node):

```
//index.js

const KinectAzure = require('kinect-azure');
const kinect = new KinectAzure();

if(kinect.open()) {
  console.log("Kinect Opened");
}
```

*(Check out the library's [/examples/node/ example](https://github.com/wouterverweirder/kinect-azure/tree/master/examples/node) to run this locally)*

But porting this over into a react build, it complains about the library's constructor, throwing an error at instantiation of `KinectAzure`. Here's my react code (do `npx create-react-app myapp` to generate the /public/index.html and /src/index.js that I have left unchanged in my app)

```
// /src/App.js

const KinectAzure = require('kinect-azure');
// import KinectAzure from 'kinect-azure'; //tried this, doesnt help
const kinect = new KinectAzure(); // error

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      blah
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: kinect.init is not a function
KinectAzure kinect-azure.js:5
js App.js:3
```

The top point in the call stack, "KinectAzure kinect-azure.js:5", is here:

```
// /node_modules/kinect-azure/lib/kinect-azure.js

const kinect = require('./binding/napi-v4/kinectAzure.node');

class KinectAzure {
    constructor() {
        kinect.init(); //HERE
    }

    // ...
}

// ...

module.exports = KinectAzure;
```

`kinect.init()` sure looks like a function to me... I can't inspect any deeper because `kinect` is loaded from a binary.

Finally, it looks like the [/lib/kinect-azure.js file was compiled from typescript](https://github.com/wouterverweirder/kinect-azure/tree/master/lib), but I'm not familiar with typescript to discern if that's a meaningful clue.

Anybody have an idea what's going on?